# AudioPlayer Plays When go to Next ViewController

Tags: ios

I have 1 `UITableViewController` contains list of songsURLs and if I `DidSelectRow` atIndexPath it goes to next `ViewController` contains `avPlayer` and play,pause, and Volume buttons I need to run The Player in Background also ,So keep the below Code in `AppDelegate.m`

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

and set the required P-list settings

But it doesn't Play The Song When navigate to my Actual tableView Class.

I need the Code That The App Continuously Plays when App Navigates from `mediaPlayerView` to `TableViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];

Comment: Actually I am Using AvPlayer , if I use the line above([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];) in AppDelegate I Get the Warning Like Incompatable type id AVAudioPlayerDelegate

Comment: Yes u need to set there.

Comment: add protocol for audioplayer <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>.

Comment: If i use Both these Lines                                                          
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
  The App Should be play in Background State But where as Active State if we go to another ViewController It Will Stops Please Help me

Comment: Sorry for delay.Plz add in your plist Application requires iPhone environment to YES.